# Detect face from video and convert it into gif

Tags: android, image, artificial-intelligence

I am doing research on topic "Face detection"  that can detect face from video and transform this into GIF format so anyone can share own expression.

I written handy algorithm to achieve this.
Let me explain you how it suppose to work :

**step1:** First video will convert this into frame as per provided fps and this will convert it into number of images.

**step2:**   Now I have frame as in form of  images they have faces and android face detection api or any other thing if you have please suggest me .It will detect faces from the images.

**Step3:** Crop those images and faces only stick with this images.

**Step4:** Get those croped file and convert this into GIF file .

So step4 is exactly my question is : How can we convert those croped images to gif formate .

I’d appreciate any information you could give me

Answer (score 1):

For the step 4, See this solution.

https://github.com/nbadal/android-gif-encoder

It's an Android version of this post.

http://www.jappit.com/blog/2008/12/04/j2me-animated-gif-encoder/

To use this class, here is an example helper method to generate GIF byte array. Note here the getBitmapArray() function is a method to return all the Bitmap files in an image adapter at once. So the input is all the Bitmap files in one adapter, the output is a byte array which you can write to the file.

```
public byte[] generateGIF() {
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = adapter.getBitmapArray();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    AnimatedGifEncoder encoder = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
    encoder.start(bos);
    for (Bitmap bitmap : bitmaps) {
        encoder.addFrame(bitmap);
    }
    encoder.finish();
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

To use this function, do the following then you can save the file into SDcard.

```
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try{
            outStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/generate_gif/test.gif");
            outStream.write(generateGIF());
            outStream.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

(Credit to lifelogger)